# How to remove duplicate table in SQL Server CE database

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact database, and it has 2 tables which are have the same name,

```
dispatch_temp_2799790924
```

So it is a temporary table, but some kind of corruption means the table is there twice. How can I clean this up?

Here is what happens. When I query this,

```
select * from __sysobjects
where [1] like '%dispatch_temp%'
order by [1]
```

It says that there are 86 rows. Also when I query this,

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name like '%dispatch_temp%'
```

I get 2 rows.

So after running this (I can only run it once),

```
drop table dispatch_temp_2799790924
```

And then running this query,

```
select * from __sysobjects
where [1] like '%dispatch_temp%'
order by [1]
```

I get 0 results.

And this,

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name like '%dispatch_temp%'
```

Returns 1 result.

So one of the tables is still there with no columns, and it all goes downhill from there. Errors occur all over the place when I try to use this database. I need to be able to remove that table from the metadata somehow?

Comment: Okay I'll admit to wondering why dispatch_temp_279979024 is like %mt_dispatch_temp%

Comment: That's a typo. dispatch_temp it is.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine couldn't open the database with management studio, but at least I could do that.

Once I had opened it, deleted one of the 2 tables, did a shrink / repair, it was looking OK.

Will have to verify the data to be 100% sure but this looks like a valid fix.